# Plotting two 2-d plots one on the top of the other in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot two 2-d plots one on the top of the other using two different palettes for each plot (my overall end is to make an animation of the two distributions with these pictures). I wrote the following snippet which is basically two panels of `multiplot` on the top of each other

```
CMD = "rm -f *.png && echo 'Initializing...'"
system(CMD)
set terminal pngcairo
PATH = '../RUNS/ZRU_0016/'
i = 900
mincb = -16
maxcb = 0
set cbrange[mincb:maxcb]
set xrange[0:201]
set yrange[0:201]
unset key
set ylabel "j"
set xlabel "i"
# This functions gives the name of the snapshot file
snapshot(i) = sprintf("snapshot_%04d.dat", i)
#-------------------------------------------------------------
    set margins screen 0.1, screen 0.85, screen 0.1, screen 0.9
    set output sprintf('%07d.png', i)
    set yrange[0:201]
    set multiplot 
    mincb = -12
    maxcb = 0
    set cbrange[mincb:maxcb]
    load 'jet.pal'
    plot PATH.'snapshots/'.snapshot(i) using 1:2:(log10($4)>mincb?(log10($4)):mincb) with lines palette lw 3, \
         PATH.'data_main_ddnls_twod_mlce.dat' u 10:11 every ::i::i  w p pt 7 lc 'black' notitle 

    mincb = -8
    maxcb = 0
    set cbrange[mincb:maxcb]
    load 'greys.pal'
    plot PATH.'snapshots/'.snapshot(i) using 1:2:(log10($5)>mincb?(log10($5)):mincb) with lines palette lw 3, \
         PATH.'data_main_ddnls_twod_mlce.dat' u 12:13 every ::i::i  w p pt 7 lc 'black' notitle 
    unset multiplot
```

I obtain a result which looks like this
[image: Plot of two distribution one on the top of the other in gnuplot]

As you can see the first distribution loaded with `jet.pal` (matlab default color scheme) should look shining, but appears to be masked by the second distribution with light greys (no worries for the colorbars).

How can I have the two distribution correct on the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you clarify the format of your data files?  It is unexpected that you are plotting "with lines" since heatmaps are usually plotted in pm3d mode or else using "with image".  In either of those modes you could assign partial transparency to the constituent pixels using the command

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
```

which would allow the first-drawn plot to show through the second plot.

Comment: Good point on `with lines` I am using,  It is a vestige of an older project where it was working fine. I update to the new proposition. Looks, better.